# Thats a lot of wasd's

Tags: cipher

*S*olve the following code

> dd ddddw ssaa wawasa
>   ddw ds wasawa
>   w d ds ds
>   aw aa d ssdwdsd
>   wwd ssaa
>   aaw dwdsdwd ssaaa wwdddd ssaaa awasawasaw dds sw dddww
>   ssd

*That is a lot of a, s, w, d's*

I don't believe any hints are needed, but I will just say that the fullstop is at the end of the cryptogram.

Comment: WASD gaming no stop

Comment: Nice puzzle, took me a while to understand it after Glen O's answer, but when I did I really liked the way of encoding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It says...

> find the 34th term in fibonacci.

and the answer (assuming the first two are 1 and 1) is

> 5702887

You have to start at s, and then it should be obvious. I won't say more, so people can discover it for themselves.

EDIT: Now that a couple of days have passed, I'll elaborate a bit further...

> Starting on the letter "s" on a QWERTY keyboard, move around on the keyboard based on the letter sequence, where "w" is up, "s" is down, "d" is right, and "a" is left, as is commonly used in gaming.
>
>  From the starting point, it begins with "dd", which is two steps right, which brings us to the first letter, "f". Then "ddddw" is four right and one up, which gets us to "i". Next is "ssaa" which is two down and two left, which puts us on "n". And then "wawasa" is a roundabout path requiring one up and three left, which leads us to "d". It continues like this, with new lines indicating the start of new words.
>
>  If you've done it right, the final line just has "ssd", which should land you on the full stop (known as "period" in America).

Comment: I started at D and ended up with gibberish. :P This makes way more sense. Too bad there wasn't a hint as to the starting point.

Comment: @IanMacDonald - there was... but not to the starting point. The hint was to the ending point.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't pick up on that.

Comment: @IanMacDonald - I actually didn't, either, until I'd finished it. I figured it would start somewhere, so I first tried with "a", and found it producing a bit of nonsense. I knew it had to start on the middle row, but I was thrown when it went up to the numbers. When I realised it might work with numbers, I checked whether a shift would help, noticed the "th" with a single right shift, and worked from there. Only noticed the fullstop when I finished.

Comment: Please could you explain this a little more? I still don't understand the encryption method, although I'm guessing it's something to do with computer keyboards. You say "so people can discover it for themselves", but that's what spoilertags are for!

Comment: @randal'thor - I meant that I wanted to not spoil it at all, because it was a good puzzle. I'll edit a better explanation in soon. In the meantime, here are two clues that should get you there - it's QWERTY, and "ASDW" is often used in gaming to replace the arrow keys, so that you have easy access to other letters for other actions.

Comment: I admit I was annoyed that you didn't post how you got that answer until I figured it out for myself. Still may be worth adding it in when people have had enough time to ponder it on their own.

Comment: Actually there was a hint about the starting letter, wasn't there? Look closely at the very first letter of the puzzle text (excluding the title).

Comment: @randal'thor - I've updated, now, so if you were still at all confused, a full explanation is given.

Comment: I was thinking you were supposed to start with "s" at each new step, and couldn't work out how "ddddw" got you to "i". But the penny has finally dropped. Thanks for editing! :-)

Comment: Actually, the s at the start has italics, i was trying to show that it was important, (and is the start point).